# how to update my password using database in android

Tags: android, database

i am using forgotPassword in SignIn Activity using Emailaddress, here my email match in database to get a record to change my password.
my code below

```
 public String updatePassword(String newPassword ,String mEmail){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String mQuery ="update "+ TABLE_USERDETIAL + " set "+ KEY_PASSWORD +"="+newPassword+" where " +mEmail;
    db.execSQL(mQuery);
    return mEmail;
}
```

the above code written in dataBase where my record will be updated.

my question is how to code to change my password of the particular mail address.

ForgotPasswordActivity

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private  EditText edtPassword;
private  EditText edtConformPassword;
private Button btnRegister;
private TextView txtEmail;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    edtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
    edtConformPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_conform_password);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mEmail = intent.getStringExtra("KEY_EMAIL");
    txtEmail.setText(mEmail);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mEmail = txtEmail.getText().toString();
            String newPassword = edtPassword.getText().toString();
            String mMail = databaseHelper.updatePassword(mEmail,newPassword);
            if (edtPassword.equals(edtConformPassword)){
                if (){

                }
            }
        }
    });}}
```

can help me in code after if (edtPassword.equals(edtConformPassword)){  in ForgotPasswordActivity